# Java Hadoop FileSystem object to File object

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have a Java code sample that uploads a file to S3

```
 File f = new File("/home/myuser/test");

    TransferManager transferManager  = new TransferManager(credentials);
    MultipleFileUpload upload = transferManager.uploadDirectory("mybucket","test_folder",f,true);
```

I would actually like to upload from HDFS to S3. I don't want to do anything complicated, so I was wondering if I can use the code that I already have. So is there a way to transform a Hadoop FileSystem object to a File object? Something like this:

```
FileSystem fs = ... // file system from hdfs path
File f = fs.toFile()
```

Thanks,
Serban

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way than downloading the HDFS file to your local file system if you want to use the `File` class. The reason is that `File` can only represent a local file on your HDD. However, from Java 7 onwards, you can use the `Path` object to obtain an input stream to your file on HDFS:

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration
// set the hadoop config files
conf.addResource(new Path("HADOOP_DIR/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("HADOOP_DIR/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

Path path = new Path("hdfs:///home/myuser/test")
FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(path)
// do what ever you want with the stream

fs.close();
```